# Is it possible to convert geotools GridCoverage2D to gdal java bindings Dataset without writing into file system

Tags: java, gdal, geotools

I am creating a geoserver wps process. The geoserver wps input provides a tiff data in geotools GridCoverage2D format. I want to convert it into gdal java binding's Dataset. Is there any way I can directly convert it into Dataset without writing into file system?

Currently I am writing the coverage into file system and opening with gdal java binding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have installed the [GDAL datastore](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/imageio.html) correctly you can write a GridCoverage out to it in the same way as any other coverage store.